# EventSetter for non-routed event?

Tags: wpf, xaml, event-handling, triggers, styles

I have a `Label` that I'm trying to change the `MouseDown` event for if a user is logged in or not by using a `Trigger`.

```
<Label x:Name="lblSave" MouseDown="lblSave_MouseDown" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" ToolTip="Save Files"  Width="25" Height="25" Margin="0, 0, 5, 0"  >
<Label.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=saveIcon}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static sec:Security.Instance}, Path=IsLoggedIn}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=readonlyIcon}" />
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="lblNoAccess_MouseDown" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Label.Style>
```

But, contrary to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139755/how-to-put-a-mousedown-event-in-a-style) post, what I have won't work because `MouseDown` is not a routed event. I'm still getting the `System.Windows.EventSetter.Event` error: `{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: value"}`.

So my question is, is there a way to use a trigger to set non-routed events?

Comment: MouseDown *is* a routed event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventsetter.aspx):

> Note that only Style.Setters supports EventSetter objects. Triggers (TriggerBase and derived classes) do not support EventSetter.

*(Also as noted in the comment, [`MouseDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousedown.aspx) is routed.)*

Answer (score 0):

Like H.B. said you can't use EventSetter in a Triggers collection, you should check in the event handler if it is logged or not and execute the right code, doesn't this solution work for you?

Comment: It would, but I want to do this to a couple items and didn't want to repeat the code in every handler. I suppose I could do a common handler though.

Comment: There's an other use case for this: I want to inherit from style and override a single method call so it goes to my class. Apparently thanks to this, I can't